# Some clarification on reusable charts

Tags: d3.js

In '[Towards Reusable Charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)', Mike lays out an example [time-series chart](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/time-series-chart.js) at the end. In it, he has this line:

```
// Select the svg element, if it exists.
var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);
```

This is happening within the definition of a reusable chart object. I am having a hard time grasping this statement.

1. First, why use `select(this)`? Is the `this` context the current instance of the chart object? If so, why bother, why not just go ahead and select the svg elements on the page?
2. Why the `selectAll`? Doesn't each chart object correspond to one chart?
3. Why `[data]`, instead of just `data`, like in most other examples I've seen? Further, why are we binding the data to the svg element, rather than to (say) the path elements?

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: It seems like the data is being bound to `svg` so the svg element can be created & updated in the same function. Is this correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A reusable chart, as defined in the article, can be used for *inserting* the chart to any DOM element, possibly multiple times on the same page, albeit with different `data`. Moreover, owing to the statement you have pointed out, it can be used to *update* a graph which already exists within a DOM element. The way it would be used is (from the [article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/)):

```js
var formatDate = d3.time.format("%b %Y");

var chart = timeSeriesChart()
             .x(function(d) { return formatDate.parse(d.date); })
             .y(function(d) { return +d.price; });

// Put the chart _inside_ #example1
d3.select("#example1")
  .datum(data1)
  .call(chart);

// Put the same chart _inside_ #example2
d3.select("#example2")
  .datum(data1)
  .call(chart);

// Update the data for #example1, without appending another <svg> element
setInterval(function () {
    d3.select("#example1")
      .datum(data2)
      .call(chart);
}, 5000);
```

Now to address your concerns of *how* it does that:

1. First note that this code is run inside `selection.each(...)`. As per the API reference, the `this` context inside [.each](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-each) is the DOM element. The API reference further goes to say:

   > The each operator can be used to process selections recursively, by using d3.select(this) within the callback function.

   So `d3.select(this)` just returns a `d3.selection` containing only the current DOM element, which may or may not contain an `<svg>` element inside it. Selecting a/every `<svg>` element on the page will not result in a very reusable chart since it'll mess with the complete page instead of only the DOM element you want the chart to appear in.
2. Using `selectAll` creates a new grouping of elements for D3 to work on, opposed to `select` which preserves the original grouping. See this [article](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#conclusion) for more details on how nested selections work. And, yes, you are right that the `selectAll` group here will be used to create or update only one `<svg>` element, which brings us to the next point.
3. One of the underlying concepts behind D3 is [data-joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/), where an *array* of data is *joined* to an group of DOM elements in a *one-to-one* fashion. In this case, we are interested in appending/updating some `data` to exactly one `<svg>` element. Using `[data]` provides us with a one-element array which can be bound to one `<svg>` element. Alternatively, this could have been written as:

```js
  var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([1]); // No `data`

   // Update the area path.
   g.select(".area")
      .data(data)    // Specifying data explicitly
      .attr("d", area.y0(yScale.range()[0]));

   // Update the line path.
   g.select(".line")
      .data(data)   // Specifying data explicitly
      .attr("d", line);
```

However, it is more *pleasing* to have data already available to the sub-selections by binding it to the `<svg>` element.

Comment: Thanks! That definitely cleared things up. One quick follow-up: is the data bound to the svg automatically available to all its child nodes? I was trying to use it to draw two paths that were grandchildren (svg>g>path) but it didn't seem to work. I had to re-bind the data to those specific paths. But there is a way to use the svg data, right?

Comment: It depends on whether you were adding the children using `selectAll` followed by a join or a plain `append`. Can you post your code (possibly as a separate question or in the original question) for review?

Comment: @musially_ut New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675237/when-is-data-bound-to-a-parent-available-to-its-children

Answer (score -5):

Reusable chart is nothing but the charts should already created we can simply get benefit of the charts.we don't need to spend time to create a charts from scratch.

Credits: [Reusabe Charts for d3](http://www.queryhome.com/62167/reusable-charts-in-d3)