# How should the layout of a HTML be constructed in order to have several interconnected charts in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to be able to link several charts such that one changes with the other. But I am not sure if

1. I should have a separate div for each chart and create svg in the second div based on an event in the svg inside first div
2. I should create another svg inside the same div on an event trigger
3. Create an svg withing another svg (if it's possible)
4. Have all charts in 1 div 1 svg maybe

Note: Data is shared by all the graphs I intend to plot.

Kindly suggest ! At the moment, I am not able to get any of these to work.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32458325/dynamically-generating-multiple-d3-svg-graphs) thread

Comment: Hi, Thank You ! But I have fixed number of charts. Except that the data is inside the first svg I created since I had only 1 graph. Now I want to create another  but using the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the `<svg>` elements, but those are merely a placeholder to plot the charts in.

The main thing you'd need to do is read the data you want to plot and store it inside a global variable, or pass it to the functions that draw the individual charts.

```
function drawLineChart(data) {
  var lineChart = d3.body.append('svg').classed('line-chart', true);
  // draw a line chart here
  return lineChart;
}

function drawBarChart(data) {
  var barChart = d3.body.append('svg').classed('bar-chart', true);
  // draw a bar chart here
  return barChart;
}

function registerEventListeners(charts) {
  // given an array of charts, register `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`,
  // or `click` event listeners for each one, and, within their handlers,
  // also change the other charts you've passed.
}

d3.csv('data', function(data, error) {
  // read the data and call the other functions with it
  var charts = [
    drawLineChart(data),
    drawBarChart(data),
  ];
  registerEventListeners(charts);
});
```